# How to stop Clang's static analyzer from analyzing Boost sources?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, clang-static-analyzer

I am trying to plug Clang's analyzer into an existing build system of a big project. I've made quite some progress, but one thing that is quite irritating is this:

```
/var/fpwork/boost_1.46.1/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:53:19: warning: Value stored to 'res' during its initialization is never read           
        int const res=pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&internal_mutex);                                                                                              
                  ^~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                               
/var/fpwork/boost_1.46.1/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable.hpp:53:19: note: Value stored to 'res' during its initialization is never read              
        int const res=pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&internal_mutex);                                                                                              
                  ^~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Quite obviously this is an warning that does not originate in our code, just in Boost sources, pulled in by an include. How can I tell Clang to ignore those, or, alternatively, how to effectively filter out all the warnings that originate there?

I've heard about `__clang_analyzer__` macro, but I'd prefer not to alter the entire codebase just to run Clang's analyzer conveniently on it.

Edit: I do agree that this mostly isn't a path where Boost usually lives; I'll leave [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) in anyway.

Comment: have you tried `-isystem`? (I use that, but I don't use static analyzer)

Comment: @sehe, no, I did not, will try.

Comment: @sehe, thanks, that helped. Can you post that as an answer?